# Missing Channel Offset in Sequence 0 Source Room:X Target Room:Y in altium

Tags: altium

I just followed this [Page](https://www.altium.com/solution/multi-channel-design-with-a-flat-project) for a simple project but I get

> Missing Channel Offset in Sequence 0 Source Room:X Target Room:Y in Altium
>   [image]

error. I have set/checked all the components channel offsets, but everything seems correct.

Here is my projet:
[enter link description here](https://easyupload.io/wkwsuw)

I will be thankful if you could help me.

Comment: Check out this link. Maybe it helps you:
https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/431954

.The forum's language seems to be German. You can translate the whole page by the Chrome's translator. (appears in the right side of the browser's address bar)

Comment: Thank you, Nima, but it didn't cover my question.